# Improving security of passing permissions to UI from the backend

Tags: django

I am working a django-angular application that is based on permissions to build the UI. Initially, I was passing the list of permissions assigned to the user to the UI as they are (.e.g add_user). But I was instructed by the CTO to change each into numerical or other form of encryption so add_user for e.g. becomes 311.

Can someone really enlighten me how this exactly improves the security of the app? The backend now sends 311 etc to the front end but now, I have to keep track of numbers ->permisions. The backend still checks permissions based on add_user kind.

Is this the way to go to improve the overall security of the app?

Answer (score 1):

It adds obscurity and does not improve security. CTO is a title and does not mean that the person understands security.

Encryption does improve security but needs to be done correctly and that is not easy. If the concern is the data in transit needs to be secure use HTTPS, that encrypts all the data, even the URL query string and server path.

Comment: Thanks @Zaph. It is already on HTTPS but his arguement is people shouldn't know the exact 'names' of permissions used at the backend. He is more experienced than me in the field so I was curious if his experience had thot him something but I failed to see how it improves security. Thanks for validating my thoughts.